# Namespace autoloading error in composer

Tags: php, laravel-4, namespaces, composer-php

I installed a php library usign composer:

```
composer require evernote/evernote-cloud-sdk-php dev-master
```

Everything went well and the library was installed. The namespace is registered in the vendor/composer/autload_namespaces.php:

```
'Evernote' => array($vendorDir . '/evernote/evernote-cloud-sdk-php/src')
```

But when I try to use a class from that namespace

```
$oauth_handler = new \Evernote\Auth\OauthHandler($sandbox);
```

I get the "Class not found error":

```
Class 'Evernote\Auth\OauthHandler' not found
```

I should mention that my vendor file is actually a symlink to a folder located somewhere else:

```
MyApp/
   app/
   vendor/ -> ../../vendor
```

I'm not sure if it has any relevance but I'm using the Laravel framework.
What can be the problem?

Comment: Just to be sure, please run `composer dump-autoload`

Comment: I already did that without success...

Comment: Can you check if the actual file exists? Sometimes something goes wrong during the installation...

Comment: Yes, it's there. I've double checked. I also did a reinstall, but nothing change. Same error.

Comment: I assume all other stuff in the vendor directory is working fine?

Comment: I just checked and some of the libraries are loaded (Monolog and Illuminate) but all the others are not working. That's very strange. I guess I'll make a fresh install because I have no idea what's happening there. Anyway, thank you for your assistance @lukasgeiter

Comment: That's weird indeed. Let me know if you find something out.

Comment: Check your composer.json path. You might need to do a "php composer.phar update" or "composer update" (depending on how you installed composer). Also, what does your "composer global show -i" sais?